# backbuttondisplaymode in swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

In UIKit, [UINavigationItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem) has this useful property called [backButtonDisplayMode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/3656350-backbuttondisplaymode) that can be used to configure the behavior of the back button.

I was just wondering if SwiftUI has something similar? Alternatively, what is the best way to achieve this in SwiftUI? I would prefer to not have to use a custom back button, and really just want the back button to say "Back" instead of the previous view's navigation title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do a custom button because SwiftUI is declarative, not imperative, but they are pretty simple.

```
struct CustomBackButton: View {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }) {
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                            Text("Back")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Not sure why I thought it'd be more difficult to replicate. I submitted an edit that adds `.font(Font.body.weight(.semibold))` to the Image to replicate the default system back button.